# AtlasSimInterface Library source code

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

AtlasSimInterface library is open source? If so, where can I find the source code?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3619/atlassiminterface-library-source-code/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

AtlasSimInterface library is not an open source library, only the binary version and headers are available.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/355/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks for the info!